# Hazelcast insert and update

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast IMDG in my application.

I have a requirement like

1] When I post the data, insert in both db and hazelcast.

2]When I get the data, it should be from hazelcast.

3]When delete the data, do it the both the side..

which is the best option to that.

Can I with MapStore in the hazelcast.?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what `MapStore` does.

One caveat: `MapStore` inherits from `MapLoader`. You'll need to return `null` for loading operations.

Hence, I'd recommend you inherit yourself from `MapAdapter` which is a no-op implementation of `MapStore`.